# Искажение верстки при динамической генерации контента

Tags: php, вёрстка

обычным скриптом добавляю циклом комментарии из бд, но тут взглянул на верстку, и вот что увидел:

[image: 2341]

как вы можете видеть добавляются много пробелов и верстка получается ломанной... почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не верстка едет, а код страницы... это большая разница...

Собственно, вы ответ, по сути, сами дали. Потому, что он динамически генерируется. А в шаблоне черт знает, что у вас написано. Может там у вас цикл, в цикле `if` в нем еще цикл, в нем еще `if`, а потом только текст выводится. И все эти вложенности отформатированы по `tab`. Может у вас текст не обрезан через `trim`....

Вам не нужно сильно об этом беспокоится. С динамически генерированным контентом это обычное дело..И этого не избежать. Но это не является чем-то критичным.

Можете для примера открыть код этой страницы и посмотреть. Тут все тоже самое.

Вот если бы у вас реально верстка бы ехала, дело другое